# Convert loop to Maybe monad

Tags: c#, functional-programming, option-type

Recently I tried applying [Maybe monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29) pattern in my C# code using [this](https://github.com/hazzik/Maybe) library.

What I found difficult to grasp was converting such a function into Maybe paradigm:

```
public Maybe<object> DoSomething(IReader reader)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var result = reader.Read();
        if (result == null) return Maybe<object>.Nothing;
        if (result.HasValue) return new Maybe<object>(null);
    }
}
```

I would like to have it written using `from x in X` form. The functionality that stands behind this function is to read `IReader` until it returns a value (`Maybe` has a value) or an error occurs (`null` gets returned).

Comment: First off, you forgot to ask a question. Are you asking for help understanding the Maybe monad? Or for help understanding how LINQ relates to monads?  Or for someone to write some code for you?  Ask an actual question please. Second, I don't understand the code; it appears that the method either returns a "nothing" or a wrapped null; of what use is that?

Comment: The method was intended to skip several reads on `IReader`. The question is how to write it using `from` form. I'm currently learning `Maybe` and got stuck on that part

Comment: the answer to your comment/question is: you don't - yeah you could try it using recursive calls but this might fail horrible in C# and you are way better of with the `while`

Comment: @Carsten thanks. Put your comment as a response and I'll accept it as an answer

Comment: I kindof did ;) - but if you want sure - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to your comment/question is: you don't - yeah you could try it using recursive calls but this might fail horrible in C# and you are way better of with the while

`from x in X` is just the *monadic - bind* (it get's translated into the `SelectMany` functions) and there is just no direct way in the LINQ syntax  for this.

But you can write your own function like this:

```
public tValue DoUntilSome<tValue>(Func<Maybe<tValue>> f)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var x = f();
        if (x.HasValue) return x.Value;
    }
}
```

and call like (see below)

```
var result = DoUntilSome(() => TryRead(reader));
```

#### remarks

first the `Maybe<object>` (`object`) part is a smell - because you most certainly want a concrete type in there instead of the generic `object`

Then `new Maybe<object>(null)` is **very** strange too

I would have suggested something like:

```
public Maybe<tValue> TryRead<tValue>(IReader reader)
{
    var result = reader.Read();
    if (result == null || !result.HasValue) 
        return Maybe<tValue>.Nothing;
    return new Maybe<tValue>((tValue)reader.Value);
}
```

then of course this part is there to get some `Maybe` value - the thing you are trying to do with `from x in X` is the monadic-bind - which you can only use **once** you have a `Maybe` to start with:

```
from value in TryRead<tValue>(reader)
from other in TrySomethingDifferent(value) // here is the bind
select ....
```

#### disclaimer

I did not compile any of this (because I was to lazy to download the github project and stuff) - put you should be able to easily solve any syntax errors that might hide there - **sorry for that**

In case you have major troubles just leave a comment